# how to append html to the sql query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, resultset

i have a sql query, i want to append the html in it and return the resultset into single cell below is my query

```
SELECT TOP (@TOP) C.Title FROM CrossArticle_Article C
    INNER JOIN CrossArticle_ArticleToCategory A2C
    ON C.Id = A2C.ArticleId
    INNER JOIN CrossArticle_Category CC
    ON A2C.CategoryId = CC.Id
    INNER JOIN crossarticle_url CU
    ON C.Id = CU.articleid
    WHERE CC.Id = @CategoryID
    AND CC.PortalId = 6
    GROUP BY C.TITLE, CU.URL, C.PublishDate
    ORDER BY C.PublishDate DESC
```

currently it will display in row, i want in single cell with html appended to it.
like below `<li><span><a href='+CU.URL+'>C.Title</a></span></li>`

Please reply if anyone have any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the how...

```
SELECT TOP(@TOP) '<li><span><a href=''' + CU.URL + '''>' + C.Title + '</a></span></li>'
FROM...
```

As for the Why...  You might be better-off building this in your mark-up...not sure what your requirements may be, but blending your data layer with your presentation layer can have some drawbacks.

Comment: thanks, i just got that myself... anyways thanks a lot for your support, i now want to add a class to the last row under li.. how could i get that.

Comment: Glad to help.  If you mark this as the answer, and then ask your second question seperately (new post), I'll be glad to help again!

Comment: HI Kuru, can you please comment on the below post..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973553/drawbacks-for-implementing-presentation-layer-inside-data-layer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP (@TOP)
       '<li><span><a href="'+CU.URL+'">'+C.Title+'</a></span></li>' AS TheColumn
  FROM
       CrossArticle_Article C INNER JOIN
       CrossArticle_ArticleToCategory A2C ON
                                             C.Id=A2C.ArticleId
                              INNER JOIN
       CrossArticle_Category CC ON
                                   A2C.CategoryId=CC.Id
                              INNER JOIN
       crossarticle_url CU ON
                              C.Id=CU.articleid
  WHERE
        CC.Id=@CategoryID
    AND CC.PortalId=6
  GROUP BY
           C.TITLE,
           CU.URL,
           C.PublishDate
  ORDER BY
           C.PublishDate DESC
```